# Menu fixed que aparezca en determinado div con HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css, menu

Quiero hacer un menu sticky pero que aparezca en determinado div osea:

Que mi **nav** dentro del **header** este normal fija pero cuando haga scroll y llegue al main aparezca el mismo **nav** y me siga hasta abajo de todo.
Como podria generar un evento que de alguna manera en main haga aparecer ese **nav** para luego hacerlo fixed???

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo podrías hacer con Intersection Observer, es una API del navegador, que lee cuando un elemento del DOM entra en la pantalla.

Podrías hacer que al inicio el menú este fijo en un punto, pero cuando el main entre en la pantalla, cambiarle la posición al menú a una fixed, o sticky.

Este video explica muy bien como funciona el intersection observer sí te hace falta: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVsqA4NhDoI